# handling c executable file using java

Tags: java, process, exec, runtime.exec

I want to run a C/C++ program's exe file using java.......and handle its input and output......

my code is

```
import java.io.*;

class run2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

    String[] command = new String[3];
    command[0] = "cmd";
    command[1] = "/C";
    // command[2] = "java Run1";
    command[2] = "start C:\\WE.EXE";

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    String i = "20";

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter st = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        p.getOutputStream()));

    String s = null;
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    s = stdInput.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    st.write(i);
    st.newLine();
    st.flush();
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println("Stdout: " + s);
    }

    try {
      System.out.println("Exit status = " + p.waitFor());
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    stdInput.close();
   }
}
```

i am getting an error which says pipes is closed
do help me out.....

Comment: Please include the complete error with traceback and everything

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, if there isn't a `WE.EXE` in `C:/`, that could be an issue. If no process is ever launched, of course you can't do anything with its input/output pipes.

However, presuming you have a `WE.EXE`, your error is probably at:

```
st.flush();
```

Your application is opening up `WE.EXE` in command prompt, or cmd.exe, who will take care of both standard input and standard output. Your call `stdInput.readLine();` will wait until `WE.EXE`, and therefore `cmd.exe`, terminates, at which point the output stream will be closed (and you obviously can't write onto a closed pipe).

So if you want to handle input and output yourself, you should launch `WE.exe` directly, like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C://WE.EXE");
```

Additionally, you may consider using [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).

---

Small detail, but consider using [Java's naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java)--for example, your class name would be Run2 (or something more descriptive) instead of run2.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read from a stream (stdInput) that does not exist yet.
It won't exist until the WE.EXE program writes something to it.

Just wait until you send the commands to the program.
In other words, take out the first input line, and it will work fine.

```
//s = stdInput.readLine(); 
System.out.println(s);
st.write(i); 
st.newLine();
st.flush();
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
 {  System.out.println("Stdout: " + s);  }
```